# jQuery: Gather all arrays stored in an object

Tags: jquery

I have an object like below, I want to construct an array combining all the arrays of this object.

```
var my_obj = {
    2: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    41: ['ccx', 'sf', 'd', 'dd', 'ff'],
    // ... continues
};
```

What I want is to build one array combining all these arrays,

```
var finalArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ccx', 'sf', 'd', 'dd', 'ff', ...];
```

What I have tried so far,

```
var finalArray = [];
$.each(my_obj, function(i,arr){
        finalArray.concat(arr);
    });
```

But the above is not giving me the desired result. Could you please point out what is wrong, and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.concat()` returns a new array. You just need to reassign to the original variable:

```
finalArray = finalArray.concat(arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fsoakq3o/

---

Or, for a couple fewer characters, you could use `jQuery.map()`:

```
var finalArray =  $.map(my_obj, function (arr, _) {
    return arr;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ak5m4xhx/

Comment: thanks a lot, will accept your answer in about 8mins.